# Implementing a filter by user function in Laravel using dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

What is the best way to implement a dropdown filter in Laravel 5?

I have a page that contains a dropdown(inside is a list of different users) and all the posts posted by the users. The page should show only the post posted by the user selected in the dropdown.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span>Posted by: </span>              
     <div class="dropdown div-inline">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Organization
                        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
          <li role"presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">ALL</a></li>
          @foreach($organizations as $o)
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li value = {{ $o->name }} role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{{ $o->name }}">{{ strtoupper($o->name) }}</a></li>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
     </div><!--dropdown-->
</div><!--input-group-->
```

What should I put in the controller and how should I route it?

Comment: [Please see how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - I'm most specifically referring to "what did you try?"

Comment: ill show my controller and route?

Comment: only show what is necesssary.  explain what you're doing (you did that well), explain what your goal is (i see that too), explain what you've tried (various methods or even links to tutorials that you are following), and then most importantly, explain what the "unexpected behavior is".  if the issue is simply, "help me build it", it's not a good candidate for a question here.

Comment: Im so sorry. But i guess i got it working.I simply added this to my filter_search function. 

  public function filter_posts($user_id){
        $organizations = Organization::all();
        if ($user_id)
            $posts = Post::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->paginate(8);
        else
            $posts = Post::paginate(8);
        return view('posts', compact('posts', 'organizations'));
    }